# ManualResetEventSlim.Wait() - timeout in TimeSpan vs int

Tags: c#, .net, manualresetevent, waithandle

You can use either `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)` or `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout)`.

But `int.MaxValue`(2,147,483,647 - approx 24.85 days) is much less than `TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalMilliseconds` (922,337,203,685,477 - approx 10,675,199.11 days).

I suspect that there is a difference between usages of those overloads.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Reference Source for *mscorlib*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ManualResetEventSlim.cs) (.NET Framework 4.7.1):

```
public bool Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    long totalMilliseconds = (long)timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
    if (totalMilliseconds < -1 || totalMilliseconds > int.MaxValue)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout");
    }

    return Wait((int)totalMilliseconds, new CancellationToken());
}
```

`Wait(TimeSpan timeout)` checks `TotalMilliseconds` to be in bounds of positive `int` value and then calls `Wait(int millisecondsTimeout)`.

So anyway the max wait value will be `int.MaxValue`. This is also true for all `WaitHandle` inheritors.